# Is a map which sends a $3\times 3$ symmetric tensor to an element of $SO(3)$ which diagonalizes it necessarily discontinuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, rotations, symmetric-matrices, smooth-functions

For a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix $Q$, one can construct a map to $SO(3)$ which sends $Q$ to a matrix which diagonalizes it.
If $Q$ has distinct eigenvalues, there are three choices for rotation matrix: given one (guaranteed by the spectral theorem) you can always cyclically permute the columns to get two more.
Choosing one arbitrarily defines a locally smooth map.
That is, perturbing the entries of $Q$ slightly will only slightly perturb the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

However, if $Q$ has repeated eigenvalues then given $R \in SO(3)$ which diagonalizes $Q$, we also have that $R'(\theta) R$ is a valid choice, where $R'(\theta)$ is a rotation by any angle $\theta$ in the plane spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to repeated eigenvalues.
It seems reasonable to me that if we arbitrarily choose some $R$, then slightly perturbing $Q$ could give another element of $SO(3)$ which is far away from $R$ but perhaps close to $R'(\theta') R$ for some $\theta'$.

The question is then, is it possible to construct a mapping so that no such discontinuities occur, or will such a mapping always be discontinuous at elements with repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: I suspect that it is possible to do so when there are two repeated eigenvalues (i.e. at rotations by 180 degrees) but not when there are three (i.e. at the identity matrix)

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you say more on that? I'm actually only interested in *traceless* symmetric matrices, and so the case with two repeated eigenvalues is sufficient for me (unless it's the 0 matrix, at which point all bets are off). Even keywords to search would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it again, it might be impossible even in the case of only two repeated eigenvalues. Note that finding such a map in the neighborhood of a matrix with two repeated eigenvalues would be equivalent to finding such a map for $2 \times 2$ symmetric tensors in a neighborhood of the zero matrix.

Comment: Note that for such a map $f:\mathcal S_2 \to SO(2)$, $\lim_{t \to 0}f(t A)$ would necessarily yield two different answers for
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: [A key subquestion] Let $A\in \mathcal Sym_{3\times 3}$, and  consider the map $P:Mat_{3\times 3}\to \mathbb R^{3}$   that assigns to a matrix $A$ the vector $(A_{i,j})_{i<j} \in \mathbb R^{3}$. 
$U\in SO(3)$ diagonalizes $A$ iff $P(U^{-1} A U) = 0$.
Suppose that $U_0$ diagonalizes $A$, question: is  the differential of $U\mapsto P(U^{-1} A U)$ at $U_0$ an isomorphism for any $A$?

Comment: Also another piece of information which might come in handy is: what is the stabilizer of a symmetric matrix under the adjoint action of $SO(3)$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can you explain why the problem for two repeated eigenvalues is the same as the problem for a $2\times 2$ in the neighborhood of the zero matrix? I'm not sure the rationale, but it seems more akin to a $2\times 2$ in the neighborhood of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, discontinuities at repeated eigenvalues are essential for such a map. If $Q_0$ has a repeated eigenvalue and thus freedom to choose $R'(\theta)R,$ then for any choice of $\theta$ you can find $Q$ arbitrarily close to $Q_0$ such that $R'(\theta)R$ is the *only* valid choice to diagonalize $Q.$

For a concrete example, if the two-dimensional eigenspace is spanned by $e_1$ and $e_2$ (and the third eigenvalue is distinct) then $$Q_1 = Q_0 + \left(\begin{matrix}
\epsilon & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right),
Q_2 = Q_0 + \left(\begin{matrix}
\epsilon & -\epsilon & 0 \\
-\epsilon & \epsilon & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

are both $4\epsilon$-close to $Q_0$ but have unique diagonalizing bases that are a full $\pi/4$ turn apart.

Comment: Can you help me flushing out what you showed here? Let's define $E$ to be the set of pairs $(A,R)$ where $A\in \mathcal Sym$ is a symmetric matrix and $R\in SO(3)$ diagonalizes $A$. Then we have a projection map $\pi: E\to \mathcal Sym $ and the question asks whether exists a section $f$ of $\pi$, such that the composition $pr_{SO(3)}\circ f:\mathcal Sym \to SO(3)$ is smooth.
The fiber of $\pi$ over $A$ is in bijection with the stabilizer of $A$ under the adjoint action which may vary. In particular $E$ is cannot be a fiber bundle. 
Now, I would like to phrase your answer in these terms.

Comment: It seems to me that you are saying that if the fiber at $Q_0$ contains an $\mathbb S^1$, then there are, arbitrarily near to  $Q_0$ matrices with fiber which is a point (idk if this is what you mean when you say only valid choice).
In case, how does this obstruct the existence of $f$?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain: Yeah, I'm thinking of the fibers being points, though they're really some finite set of points (due to permutations). The fact that the fibers are points is not enough for an obstruction; the key point that these fibers do not "come together" as you move towards $Q_0$. In my example (forgetting permutations) the fiber over $Q_i(\epsilon)$ would be the point $(Q_i, R_i)$ where $R_1, R_2$ are distinct elements of $SO(3)$. As $\epsilon \to 0,$ these remain the same distance apart, so continuity is impossible. Not sure what the bundle machinery gets you here.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's much more clear!  About the bundle machinery, I agree, it's subjective, for me it is useful to express the problem in geometric terms and create a picture to keep in mind about what's going on. Also, now I have an easy-to-remember idea of how to attack similar problems in the future.